# The strange internal indent of WPF WrapPanel

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

I have WPF WrapPanel, and a toolbar inside. The WrapPanel is red and the toolbar is blue.

[image]

Could anybody explain me, where did indent of WrapPanel on the top, left etc. come from, and how I can remove it?

Here is the sample code of the image:

```
<WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Background="Red">
       <ToolBar x:Name="tFirst" Background="Blue" ToolBarTray.IsLocked="True">
         <Button ToolTip="New" Content="New" />
         <Button ToolTip="Save" Content="Save" />
         <Button ToolTip="Delete" Content="Delete" />
       </ToolBar>
</WrapPanel>
```

Thanks in advance.

UPDATE: the problem is only with Toolbar, I just changed WrapPanel to DockPanel, and the problem is still exists.

Comment: It looks like there is either a `Padding` set on the `WrapPanel` or a `Margin` set on the `Toolbar`. Do you have any implicit styles set up for these elements?

Comment: No, I haven't. Further, I tried to set margin property of WrapPanel as well as and margin and padding properties of Toolbar to zero. Unfortunately, the padding property is absent in the WrapPanel. Also you can try it yourself on the simple project. Just add my sample code to your window and see the results.

Comment: Have a look at Snoop (http://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/). The tool really helps in analyzing this kind of problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably something about the default, built-in control template of the `ToolBar` control.

A quick fix is, obviously, to set `Margin` to -2 for example.

`ToolBar` is internally quite complex, it consists of a `Grid`, a `Border`, a `DockPanel` etc. you can try and traverse it with `VisualTreeHelper`. For example:

```
var dockPanel = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(tFirst, 0), 1), 0);
```

retrieves the `DockPanel` object. You can try and find the control with `Margin` or `Padding` greater than 0, and if you succeed you could probably even reset it from code (something like: `(dockPanel as DockPanel).Margin = 0;`)

In XAML, I'd try overriding `ToolBar's` control template (as demonstrated in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970772(v=vs.85).aspx - although this example is of course overly complex for your purpose, the principle is the same).

Comment: Thanks you for the advice! I think that I should to do like this :(